# How can I copy a block on one page to another page retaining css stylings?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I've got two pages whose javascript can talk to each other, via the return value of window.open(), or window.opener. The pages can (and typically will) have completely different css rules.

I pick an arbitrary node in the DOM heirachy of one page (say, a DIV element).  I now insert a clone of it into the other document, at some arbitrary (but legal) location in the hierarchy.

Now I also want to create css rules that keep it looking similar on the new page. I prefer minimal number of properties on the css rules.

Can I do this by doing some kind of comparison of styles and computed styles on the DOM elements of both documents? Would it help if I were to remove the classes from elements temporarily, or otherwise modify them, so that I can get the computed styles on the elements with "default" styles, and compare to that?

Comment: Check the DOM Storage guide

Comment: Not sure if it works in your case, but you can draw the DOM onto a canvas; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas. But if you need to be able to interact with it as well I guess this won't work.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/1ruvsqw1/1/

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0],
    div = e.cloneNode(true),
    newStyles = getComputedStyle(e);
document.body.appendChild(div);
var existingStyles = getComputedStyle(div);
for (var i in existingStyles) {
    console.log(i, existingStyles[i]);
    if (newStyles[i] != existingStyles[i]) div.style[i] = newStyles[i];
}
```

Just copy the computed styles over in a for-in loop.

Comment: I wanted to reduce the number of styles.  Also I had hoped to do it in terms of css classes rather than inline styles.  Is this impossible?

Comment: This answer is very inefficient that way - it iterates over all default styles as well which would come down to 200+ for each element. With JavaScript's cssRules you can access the stylesheet directly and copy only the relevant CSS. http://tinyurl.com/oukh4fw

Comment: @rob If you're using classes, you'll need to include all the stylesheets of the other page.

Comment: @bjb568 My intention was only to copy over the ones that are needed.  I don't know if this is possible, but that's what I was hoping for.  It seems like someone would have attempted to solve this, but maybe not.

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks, that's a lot better.  I'll still see if I can get a solution that actually creates css rules rather than inline css, but this is certainly a start.